# How to count number of elements between elements of some sorted vector?

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors:
First have many values between 0 and 1
Second vector have 100 values(intervals) between 0 and 1: [0 0.01 0.02 .... 1] where 0 0.01 is first interval, 0.01 0.02 second and so on.
I need to create vector, where each element is the number of occurrences of elements of the first vector in each interval from second.
For example:
first [0.00025 0.0001 0.0011 0.0025 0.009 ...(a lot of values bigger then 0.01) ... 1]
then first element of result vector should be 5, and so on.
Any ideas how to implement this in matlab?

Comment: [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) does exactly what you want.

Comment: yes, it's work like i wanted, thanks!